# Conditional statements in R Shiny server.R

Tags: javascript, json, r, shiny

I succesfully created a Shiny app which is interfaced with a javascript program using the Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler() function. The javascript program then returns a JSON to Shiny. Next step would be to check the JSON which the javascripts returns and depending of the type perform a specific action in R Shiny. I have this snippet from server.R which should fulfill this requirement:

```
  eventReactive(input$jsQLK,{
    b <- fromJSON(input$jsQLK)
    if(is.null(b) || is.na(b)){
      print('0')
    }
    else if(b$result$Layout$Type == "A"){
      print('yay')
    }
    else if(b$result$Layout$Type == "B"){
      print('nay')
    else
      print('k')
  })
```

The javascript running alongside it, looks like this:

```
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("tx", Tx);
//Other code and creation of websocket
  function Tx(msg){
    ws.send((msg.req));

    ws.onmessage = function (event) {
      console.log(event.data);
      Shiny.onInputChange('jsQLK',event.data);
    }
  }
```

Running this, nothing gets printed. If I use observeEvent, I got the error: "Error in if: argument is of length zero" and ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer

How can I succesfully achieve this?

Comment: have a look at the `Shiny.onInputChange` and this https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I use Shiny.onInputChange in the javascript file. And succesfully displaying the JSONs in my Shiny app works. I'd like to have a conditional statement before the displaying of the JSON.

Comment: `eventReactive` has to be bound to output or other reactive in order to trigger. try with `observeEvent`

Comment: When used I got this following error: ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer. Thats the reason for asking, I was hoping there was another solution

Comment: You know its hard to help you with little info, im just speculating what could be wrong, can you provide a full example. Also add this as a first line `req(input$jsQLK)`

Comment: My apologies, I didn't want to overclutter the page with code. I added the javascript file

Comment: There is no such thing as too much code. It really would be helpful with complete code for an app displaying your problem.